# Which dialect of English do people pronounce advertisement as ad-VER-tis-ment

Tags: pronunciation, dialects

I recently listened to an audio book in which the narrator had pronounced advertisement as ad-VER-tis-ment, and thought this was a strange way of pronouncing it, so I'm curious to know in which part of the united States he could've possibly gotten that from.

The t in between VER and tis sounded blended in together like in verdict, vertices, etc.

Comment: I have lived in the US my entire life, in California, New York, Missouri, and Virginia, with other stops in between, and that is how all almost all educated people I know pronounce *advertisement*; in other words, I don't believe it breaks down regionally.

Comment: A second opinion, in complete agreement. I’ve lived in Chicago, Boston, New York, Washington, D.C., LA, and San Francisco, and always said it and heard it this way.

Comment: Ad-VER-tis-ment is the standard British pronunciation - see https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/newstopics/howaboutthat/8305645/The-conTROversy-over-changing-pronunciations.html

Comment: Maybe the Narrator was from New England, or had previously lived in Britain, unless he dubbed his accent to sound more like a U.S. native.
I've also heard some narrators pronounce it ad-ver-TISE-ment instead of AD-ver-tise-ment.

Comment: @HeavenlyHarmony How would you pronounce it? AD-ver-tise-ment?

Comment: @choster That's interesting; I've lived in Michigan my whole life and I don't think I've ever heard an American say anything but AD-ver-tise-ment.

Comment: @KateBunting That's true, but a lot of English Midland and Northern dialects have (or at least used to have, I haven't heard it recently) adverTISEment which is different both from British RP and the Michigan pronunciation given by Tanner Swett. I wonder whether it's do with the general rhythm of speech.

Comment: Probably the same people that shorten it to adverts instead of just ads. I was about fifty the first time I heard anything other than adverTISEments, and had lived in twenty different states and visted all fifty by then. So it's starting sound more like social class split than geographical. This *only* gives the above pronunciation - [ad·vr·taiz'·muhnt](https://www.google.com/search?q=pronounce+advertisement&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US727&oq=pronounce+advertisement&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.7790j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Even better - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vDoN0BllhPY

Answer (score 6):

[British English](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/advertisement) always accents the second syllable of *advertisement* — *adVERtisement* — but the s may be voiced to a z-sound or not.

The forvo.com collection of [user-submitted audio files](https://forvo.com/search/advertisement/en_usa/) shows an American pronunciation with primary accent falling on either the first or third syllable: *ADvertisement* or *adverTISEment*.

This empirically verifiable fact, however, is not acknowledged by most commonly available online resources, which apparently are also under the impression that the British pronunciation is heard enough in the US to list it second. Conversely, a [2011 article in the *Telegraph*](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/newstopics/howaboutthat/8305645/The-conTROversy-over-changing-pronunciations.html) reports that a British Library study found that some younger Britons have adopted American pronunciations of a number of words, including *adverTISEment*.

While noting the non-rhotic (r-dropping) pronunciation in the East and South, the Kenyon-Knott  [*Pronouncing Dictionary of American English*](https://archive.org/details/pronouncingdicti00unse/page/7) (1949) accents the third syllable with the British listed second. This pattern, without the non-rhotic pronunciations, is followed by both [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/advertisement?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld) and [Random House](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/advertisement#).

The [*American Heritage Dictionary*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=advertisement&submit.x=38&submit.y=18) accents on the first syllable, giving the British pronunciation as an alternative. The [Wiktionary entry](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/advertisement) does the same, noting that the British pronunciation is heard “less often” in American English. The audio file provided as example, however, accents the third syllable.

The rest, I’m afraid, has to remain anecdotal. I have found no resource suggesting a regional preference for either American pronunciation over the other.

Comment: A lot of the people I know in Oldham pronounce _advertisement_ /ˌæd.vɚˈtaɪz.mənt/. 'Uk English' is becoming a very unhelpful label.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from  upstate NY, I’d always thought that “AdVERtisment” was simply pretentious in America (I’ve only heard ADvertizement from an in-the-flesh human). In Britain, I think AdVERtisment is normal, and probably also in other U.S. regions. However, I’ve only heard it pronounced that way in shows or movies and I live in an educated, upper-middle class town. So I believe that it’s not related to social class or economic standing, but simply geographical, although I wouldn’t be surprised of it varies not by region but by town.

Answer (score 0):

The pronunciation varies hugely.

OED, which tends towards RP in British English, gives

BRITISH ENGLISH  /ədˈvəːtᵻsm(ə)nt/uhd-VUR-tuhss-muhnt and /ədˈvəːtᵻzm(ə)nt/ uhd-VUR-tuhz-muhnt

U.S. ENGLISH /ˈædvərˌtaɪzmənt/ AD-vuhr-tighz-muhnt and /ədˈvərdəzmənt/ uhd-VUR-duhz-muhnt

https://www.wordreference.com/definition/advertisement has nine spoken accents

Random House Learner's Dictionary of American English gives
ad•ver•tise•ment /ˌædvɚˈtaɪzmənt, ædˈvɜrtɪsmənt, -tɪz-/

Random House Unabridged Dictionary of American English gives
ad•ver•tise•ment  (ad′vər tīz′mənt, ad vûr′tis mənt, -tiz-),

Collins Concise English Dictionary gives
advertisement, sometimes US advertizement /ədˈvɜːtɪsmənt -tɪz-/

and MW gives ad·​ver·​tise·​ment ˌad-vər-ˈtīz-mənt  əd-ˈvər-təz-mənt, -tə-smənt

Given the above, the simplest advice on pronunciation is "Whatever you think it is." I don't think it is useful to be prescriptive or attempt classification.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Irish and everyone here pronounces it as adverTISEments.

Comment: This would benefit from a citation.